# Any difference from Apple instructions when installing Bootcamp to dual-drive iMacs?

Tags: imac, bootcamp

Apple's Bootcamp instructions make no mention of how to proceed with a dual-drive iMac. Are there any differences in formatting/installation procedures involving either or both of the drives? I am new to Macs and don't want to muck up what is working well.

Comment: BootCamp only supports installing a partition on the same drive as the OS. Macs allow you to install an OS on pretty much any drive, so if you have two OS, one on each drive you could also have two BootCamp. Can you narrow down a bit what research or what thing about BootCamp you're not getting? Are you simply looking for the BootCamp FAQ or is there something deeper to be answered?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an internal SSD and HDD I think it comes down to which one is the boot drive. You can choose the startup disk in the Preferences pane.

You can change the startup disk by formatting the new drive with GUID in Disk Utility.

I *think* the Bootcamp partition must be on the same drive as the startup disk, so that it shows up when you press Alt during boot.

If you use an external SSD drive, Bootcamp can not start the installation on an external drive (eg. external Thunderbolt enclosure with SSD), however you can [install on the internal drive and clone the partition](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=14837526&postcount=5).

BootCamp installation on a secondary internal drives may require cloning a partition, see [this post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=14651073&postcount=4).